# android-x86 installation modes

Tags: android-x86

I recently installed android-x86 in my PC. During the installation, I came across the following pic.

[image: Android Live & Installation CD - Image]

I don't know about the VESA mode and the Debug mode. Also, I've seen terms like HDPI and LDPI in android boot menus. Can anyone make me understand about the different installation modes available for android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Breakdown of menu

- **Live CD** (no installation at all): everything will run in memory, with access to the hard drive.
- **Live CD VESA**: allows you to do things like setting graphics modes and displaying images without needing to know the hardware details for every graphics chipset.
- **Live CD DEBUG**: basically a developer mode, also for troubleshooting.
- **Install Android to hard disk**: installs to hard drive, to be accessed like a regular PC.

---

For more information about VESA see [Wikipedia: Video Electronics Standards Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Electronics_Standards_Association).

Also check out [VESA Graphic Modes - a guide](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/ug/graphics/vesa.html).